# Using 'like' in ssrs expressions

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-expression

I'm trying to highlight a field when the value has the word 'deadline' in it. I'm trying to use the expression:

`=IIf(Fields!Notes.Value like "%deadline%","Yellow","Transparent")`

in the BackgroundColor property.

It's not highlighting the field (not changing the background color).  The 'Notes' field is a text datatype and I'm using Report Builder 3.0 if that makes a difference.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SSRS does **NOT** use SQL syntax, but instead uses Visual Basic.

**Use something like this:**

```
=IIf(Fields!Notes.Value.IndexOf("deadline") >= 0,"Yellow","Transparent")
```

Or .Contains instead of .IndexOf

```
=IIf(Fields!Notes.Value.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("deadline"),"Yellow","Transparent")
```

Comment: I tried using Contains() before but I was missing the tolower() or tolowerinvariant() method to convert it from text to string.  Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by converting text to string? Aren't they the same thing?

Answer (score 47):

It is like in access: not '%' but '*':

```
=Fields!Notes.Value Like "*deadline*"
```

Comment: It is case-sensitive. FYI. Use with lowercase - 
`=IIf(LCase(Fields!Notes.Value) Like "*deadline*","Yellow","Transparent")`

Comment: Can the expression be used to look for phrases in the string like "*text with spaces*" or does it only work with single words like "*textwithoutspaces*"?

Answer (score 11):

"InStr" works for me:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!Notes.Value,"deadline")>0, "Yellow", "Transparent")
```

Remember that the compare value is case-sentive, so maybe use UCASE around:

```
=IIF(InStr(UCASE(Fields!Notes.Value),"DEADLINE"))>0, "Yellow", "Transparent")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use something like:

```
Fields!Notes.Value.Contains("deadline")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is case-sensitive. FYI. Use with lowercase - `=IIf(LCase(Fields!Notes.Value) Like "*deadline*","Yellow","Transparent")`