# IIf(Instr) in SSRS reporting error - Switch cases in SSRS Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

My report looks as below:

[image]

And my SSRS form of the report is as below:

[image]

I want only one line of total and don't want the total percentage line to show up.For this, I would like to add a case/switch statement in the expression:

```
If Column_grouping contains "percent" then show "%value" 
If column_grouping does not contain "percent" then show "total"
```

And my SSRS expression is as below:

```
​​​​​​​=Switch
(Fields!Column_Grouping.Value like "*percent*", Fields!Total_value_Count_pct.Value,
Fields!Column_Grouping.Value not like "%percent%",Sum(Fields!Total_value_Count.Value))
```

Evidently this expression is wrong. Any help to fix this?!

Comment: One of your string uses `%` and the other `*`, is that intended? Also, one return value and the other is an aggregate; does that match the grouping in your report? It seems odd that you would aggregate one column and not the other. Also, you've tagged SSRS 2008 and 2012? Which you *really* using? There's a big difference between the two.#

Comment: oops. The statement I added is having all the combinations I tried. It's wrong. I need help to fix this statement. Also pls refresh, question is edited slightly

Comment: @Larnu I'm using 2008. 2012 tag removed

Comment: An asterisk `*`should be used for LIKE in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could simplify the expression a bit and just use an `IIF` statement.  The `SWITCH` is best used with more than 2 expressions to evaluate.  Additionally, you should be able to use `InStr` or `Contains` as you indicated in the title of the question.  I would think the following expression should work.

```
= IIF(Fields!Column_Grouping.Value.Contains("percent"), 
      Fields!Total_value_Count_pct.Value, Fields!Total_value_Count.Value)
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26973618/10755978) for a more detailed explanation on how `InStr` works.  Contains will simply check if the string occurs in the field you are using it on.