# SSRS - Check if a substring is contained in a string by code

Tags: reporting-services, substring, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a report and a vb function in the code. I would like to know how can I check if a string is contained in a string. For example:

I want to check if "over" is contained in "stackoverflow". How can I do this by code in reporting services (ssrs) in a rdl file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'like' in ssrs expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009825/using-like-in-ssrs-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check substring in string using below expression, it's return either `true` or `false`.

```
Fields!MainString.Value.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("what are you looking")
```