# ssrs expression to split string every 2 characters

Tags: reporting-services, split, ssrs-2008

1. I am using SSRS to do the below functionality

   ```
   I have a string stractual= 7700964455 

   I need to split the above string for every 2 characters something like below
   ```

77
00
96
44
55

```
Also I have another string value strexist = "99"

I need to verify whether strexist exists in stractual to meet the condition.


77
00
96
44
55
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009825/using-like-in-ssrs-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009825/using-like-in-ssrs-expressions) This addresses the second part of the question; chnage to parameters rather than fields

Comment: Can the first part be handled in SQL rather than by SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic SQL Server function to do the string split would look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SPACEIT (@str nvarchar (255)) RETURNS nvarchar (500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cnt int = 1;
    DECLARE @result nvarchar (500) = ''

    WHILE @cnt <= LEN(@str)
    BEGIN
      SET @result = @result + SUBSTRING(@str,@cnt,1)
      if (@cnt % 2 = 0)
          set @result = @result + ' '
      SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    END 

    return @result
END
```

Comment: I know to write in SQL but the thing here is how to do that in SSRS level I got the solution we can so that using vb script

Answer (score 0):

To control the above the functionality in the SSRS level we can write vb script as below

[image]

Click on the report properties and move to Code tab and write your vb function

[image]

you can write your own logic something below

[image]

TO access the function you need to write something like below in the expressions

```
=Code.SubjectDetailsCheck("Value","1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use below query as a trick -

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(10)='702030405'
DECLARE @RNG INT=LEN(@VAR)
SELECT @RNG
SELECT TOP (@RNG) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.OBJECT_ID) R
INTO #TEMP  
FROM SYS.all_objects A
CROSS JOIN SYS.all_objects B

SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY R DESC) as R1 INTO #T1
FROM #TEMP


--DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(10)='7020304056'

Select CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(@VAR,R,len(@VAR)-R))>2 
THEN LEFT(SUBSTRING(@VAR,R,len(@VAR)-R),2)
ELSE SUBSTRING(@VAR,R,len(@VAR)-R) END SS
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY R)R2
INTO #T3
FROM #T1

SELECT * FROM #T3
WHERE NOT(R2% 2=0)

DROP TABLE #TEMP
DROP TABLE #T1
DROP TABLE #T3
```