# SSRS - Display "True" when what id displayed from one field is CONTAINED in another

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2012

I'm working on a report that is trying to display a simple "True" when the contents of a field is SOMEWHERE within another.

Right now I'm using for the expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Medicaid___from_Prestige.Value.Contains("Fields!Medicaid___from_PML.Value"),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

And I'm still getting False on the report.  See the picture:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'like' in ssrs expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009825/using-like-in-ssrs-expressions)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try contains ex:

```
=IIF(Fields!Medicaid___from_Prestige.Value.ToLowerInvariant(‌​).Contains(Fields!Medicaid___fro‌​m_PML.Value),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

EDIT:
Index of

```
=IIF(Fields!Medicaid___from_Prestige.Value.ToLowerInvariant(‌​).IndexOf(Fields!Medicaid___fro‌​m_PML.Value),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Comment: You're right, I did =IIF(InStr(Fields!Medicaid___from_Prestige.Value.Contains("Fields!Medicaid___from_PML.Value"),"TRUE","FALSE") and for some reason contains is triggering the red line of doom.

Comment: try removing the instr? I forgot to do that from my answer before I edited

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIF' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: I just found an example using index of I don't know if it works but marking this as duplicated because it is another SO question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009825/using-like-in-ssrs-expressions

Comment: Now I'm getting "true" on everything.

Comment: Did you switch the IndexOf("Your actual column value")

Comment: Yes I did.  It's returning true now regardless if it exists or not.

Comment: Still giving you the answer, but I modified a bit from that SO that you linked. =IIF(Fields!Medicaid___from_Prestige.Value.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(Fields!Medicaid___from_PML.Value),"TRUE","FALSE")

Answer (score 1):

I did the following, and it worked:

```
=IIF(Fields!Medicaid___from_Prestige.Value.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(Fields!Medicaid___from_PML.Value),"TRUE","FALSE")
```