# Like "%%" is not working in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I need to show all data passing through `like "%%"` in an expression just like a SQL Server. But in a runtime it is not showing the calculated value but an `#error`.
My SSRS expression is:
 `=IIf(Parameters!stateid.Value like "%%",IIf(Parameters!stateid.Value=1 or Parameters!stateid.Value=37 or Parameters!stateid.Value=38,Fields!Achivement_Financial_Total.Value *90\100,Fields!Achivement_Financial_Total.Value *60\100),IIf(Parameters!stateid.Value=1,Fields!Achivement_Financial_Total.Value *90\100,Fields!Achivement_Physical_Gen.Value *60\10))`

> Should i use something else instead of `like "%%"` or any function which supports "%%". I used `Str` function but is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'like' in ssrs expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009825/using-like-in-ssrs-expressions)

Comment: I googled _SSRS Like_ and found the answer.

Comment: Yes, but `.IndexOf()` is not accessable.

Comment: There are three other suggestions in that link. Do any of them work?

Comment: Why not just add the like clause to the dataset query instead of attempting to do it in an SSRS expression? Expressions will not behave like queries and nor should they.

Comment: Yes, I have done it in SQL Server using CASE in select cause.